# How to set environment variables to PIPENV

Tags: python, pipenv

I have pipenv virtual env and `moviepy` library installed, and it requires `ImageMagick` as dependency, and for that i need to set `IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY` path as environment variable in virtual env,

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .env file in the root directory of your project and access it using in code via the following:

```
import os
os.getenv(‘IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY’, 'IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY path not found')
```